# Edit file within rails app and save back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, markdown

I want to add this functionality but a bit unsure on ways to implement it. Basically want I want to be able to do is:

Vist the admin area of my site at /admin
Click link to edit home page content
Show contents of /app/views/pages/_home.md in a textarea
Make changes to it and save it back

Basically, just unsure if this is possible and if so, how would this fit in with my Github repo?

Kind regards,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues that you'll run into.

The first is that your application server will not pick up the changes since they are all loaded and cached when the application server is started. If your using an app server like unicorn then you would need to send it a restart signal which will take a few seconds for the new master process to spin up and your changes to become live.

The other issue that you've pointed out already is that if your doing automated deployments with capistrano then your changes will be reverted on the next deploy unless you then manually commit the same changes in the normal fashion, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Generally the way to go about handling this is to move your templates into database tables, this resolves both issues, but then means your only means of editing is through the UI.

If your still set on making this work, the first issue is fairly simple to get working. Simply shell out and execute the appropiate commands to restart your application server. On my deployments i have a unicorn control script in script/unicorn which would be triggered with `system('script/unicorn restart')`. The second issue is tougher since your going to need ssh keys for the user that the server is running as and be able to push to your repo as that user. Once you have that you can make your changes, git add, git commit and finally push. Where this will get a little dirty is having to deal with a branch that is ahead of what is deployed and having to pull/merge before being able to push. A possible solution to this would be having a specific branch (ie production branch) on github that is always synced with what is deployed. There would still be a small window between someone pushing and deploying and someone editing on the UI where a push would fail. This could also be mitigated by locking out the UI editor if the current deployed HEAD does not match the github production branch, unlocking it when the deploy syncs them up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Think I will leave this functionality out for now and just update my content as normal and commit > push. Thanks again!